# Finding out when summed values reached a certain checkpoint in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

First of all: I've found some possible answers to my problem in the previously asked questions, but I've encountered problems with getting them to work properly. I know the question was already asked, but the answers always were working code with little to no explaination on the method used.

So: I've got to find out when a customer reached the VIP status, which is when value of his orders exceeds 50 000. I've got 2 tables: one with orderid, customerid and orderdate, and second with orderid, quantity and unitprice.
The result of the query I'm writing should be 3 colums wide, one with the customerid, one with true/false named "is VIP?", and the third is the date of getting the VIP status(which is the date of order that summed with the previous ones gave a result of over 50 000)-the last one should be blank if the customer didn't reach the VIP status

```
select o.customerid, sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice),
case
when sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice)>50000 then 'VIP'
else 'Normal'
end as 'if vip'
from
orders o join [Order Details] od on od.orderid=o.orderid
group by o.customerid
```

That is as far as I got with the code, it returns the status of the customer and now I need to get the date when that happend.
.

Comment: I am not asking for the solution of the problem, I'm asking for a way of solving it, for an idea on how to approach it. There is no problem because there is no solution yet.
I'm working on the Northwind database, the question I asked is about an exercise that I found in my textbook and I have no idea how to create anything but a view(which wouldn't be very helpful I suppose) nor to insert anything.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well, yeah. I just noticed I've chosen the wrong tag, sorry.

Comment: Which database are u using?

Comment: I'm using Northwind and SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily calculate a running total using a window functions:

```
select o.customerid, 
       o.orderdate, 
       sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) over (partition by o.customerid order by orderdate) as running_sum, 
from orders o 
   join Order_Details od on od.orderid = o.orderid
order by customer_id, orderdate;
```

Now you need to find a way to detect the first row, where the running total exceeds the threshold:

The following query starts numbering the rows in a descending manner once the threshold is reached. Which in turn means the row with then number 1 is the first one to cross the threshold:

```
with totals as (
  select o.customerid, 
         o.orderdate, 
         sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) over (partition by o.customerid order by orderdate) as running_sum, 
         case
           when 
              sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) over (partition by o.customerid order by orderdate) > 50000 then row_number() over (partition by o.customerid order by orderdate desc)
           else 0
         end as rn
  from orders o 
     join Order_Details od on od.orderid = o.orderid
)
select *
from totals
where rn = 1
order by customerid;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7f18/3

Comment: This simply returns the row with the latest date :-)

Answer (score 3):

You get the cumulative sum using an Analytic Function, `SUM OVER`. And then add an aggregate to find the minimum date:

```
with cte as
 ( select o.customerid, 
      o.orderdate, 
      case when sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) -- running total
                over (partition by o.customerid
                      order by orderdate
                      rows unbounded preceding) > 50000 
           then 'Y' 
           else 'N' 
      end as VIP
  from orders o 
  join Order_Details od on od.orderid = o.orderid
 )
select customerid,
   MAX(VIP) AS "isVIP?",  -- either 'N' or 'Y'
   MIN(CASE WHEN VIP = 'Y' THEN orderdate END) AS VIP_date -- only when VIP status reached
from cte
group by customerid
order by customers;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7327f/2)

Answer (score 1):

Not going to complicate the answer with logic to show 'vip' and 'vip date'.  This will give you a running total for each customer order.

`select o.orderid, o.customerid, o.orderdate, sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) 'Total', (
      select sum(od.quantity * od.unitprice) total
        from orders o2 
             join [Order Details] od2 on od2.orderid=o2.orderid
        where o2.orderID <= o.orderID 
              and o2.customerid = o.customerid) 'RunningTotal' 
    from orders o 
         join [Order Details] od 
           on od.orderid=o.orderid
    group by o.orderid, o.customerid, o.orderdate
order by o.customerid`

Comment: You can do a running total much easier using `sum(od.quantity*od.unitprice) over (partition by o.customerid order by o.orderdate)`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on how to approach, you could consider going for an SQL trigger which runs on each update to the tables involved and sets the status when the threshold is hit.This would set the date as and when the event happens.

Another approach would be to use a stored procedure wherein you can use a loop top iterate over the records and arrive at the date.

The choice can be made based on the volume of the data, with the former bring suitable for extremely large amounts of data.